# How to use trim() function in CakePHP 2 fotm when adding data?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

How to use `trim()` function in CakePHP 2 form when adding data?

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('service_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->input('unit');
    echo $this->Form->input('price');
    echo $this->Form->input('date');
?>
```

Comment: $this->request->data['Price'] = array_map('trim',array($this->request->data['Price']['name'],
                $this->request->data['Price']['unit'],
                $this->request->data['Price']['price']));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, before you `save()` the data:

```
$this->data['YourModelName'] = array_map('trim', $this->data['YourModelName']);
```

You can also do it for each field individually instead, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for good decision.
Just not an error in the date ()